# Facing git repo clone issue with correct access rights

Tags: git, github

I am facing github issue on cloning the repo.
I am using mac and getting this issue.

'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe': C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe: command not found
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Please help me. I am curios if I am using mac so why its showing Windows

Comment: How are you trying to clone the repo?

Comment: `git config --get-regexp ssh` ? `set | grep -F GIT_SSH` ?

Comment: @holloway trying to clone it with ssh url and using the cmd git clone 'repo_url'

Comment: @phd could you explain more I ran these cmds but didn't work

Comment: @Shikha These are not commands to fix your problem. The question marks mean I asked for additional information. Run the commands, [edit] the question and copy/paste text output.